# why does this give a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, exception, radix-tree

This code is part of a method to add a word to a radix tree. if I call this method with the word in the parameter [e.g. addWord("food", node)], it throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` at the `char character = word.charAt(0);` line. I am struggling to figure out why that is. I have tried changing the number and still gets the same result.

```
    private void addWord(String word, RadixNode node) 
    {
        RadixNode childNode;
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        do
        {
            char character = word.charAt(0);
```

Comment: Have you considered the case where `word` is empty?

Comment: @Sweeper not yet, but i put the word as a parameter so i know that it's not empty in this case

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is because your String `word` is empty.

You should check for emptiness before:

```
private void addWord(String word, RadixNode node) {
  if (word.isEmpty()) {
    // do nothing
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```

You could also throw an explicit exception (eg: `IllegalArgumentException`) or handle this case.

If word should not be empty, then that's mean you have to check method calling `addWord`.

Comment: I put the word as a parameter into the method so it surely it can't be empty right?

Comment: @MohammedYakub Either [A] it is empty and therefore you get this error, or [B] some cosmic ray hit your memory banks and causes your computer to corrupt things in the exact fashion that this error occurred at random.   ---- Given that [B] is infintesimally unlikely let's just go with [A], huh :)

Comment: @rzwitserloot this is why i am confused at why this error is occurring, it SHOULD only occur if it is empty, but how can it be empty if i set a value for it?

Comment: Clearly your 'set a value' code doesn't work the way you think it does. You did not paste it. Can't  give you much more than 'that part is broken'.

Comment: @rzwitserloot btw the 'set a value' code is simply putting the word in double quotes in the parameter when calling this method, i don't see how there could be a fault in that, but i understand you would be unable to diagnose the problem without looking at more code, thanks anyway